# Is it possible to back a readonly SQLite database with a memory buffer (or PE resource)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, sqlite

I would like to embed a reasonably large chunk of data stored in a SQLite database into my binary using Windows' "custom resources" feature. (This is a whitelist for a logging tool) SQLite does come with support for [in memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), but it looks like that may be limited to creating completely new databases; and does not seem to support reading from a memory buffer; but I'm not positive.

Does the database support anything like this? (I have to embed SQLite for other reasons, so it'd be awesome to use it for whitelists too...)

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question. I do have a solution to your problem: Store the sql commands in resource, then pass that script to the SQLite engine.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yeah, that'll work, but if that's done then I can't pregenerate indexes or other such things and embed them -- they have to be done on the fly which would be expensive. (Half the point of using SQLite over a general serialization tool like protocol buffers would be to make it easy to embed pregenerated indicies)

Answer (score 2):

The online backup section of sqlite documentation http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html has some code that might do what you want (i.e. dump in memory db to file, or reload a file into an in memory db). That should allow you do save you pre-indexed db into a file that you can add to your resources and load in memory at run-time.

This is the code in question (copied straight from the page linked above)

```
/*
** This function is used to load the contents of a database file on disk 
** into the "main" database of open database connection pInMemory, or
** to save the current contents of the database opened by pInMemory into
** a database file on disk. pInMemory is probably an in-memory database, 
** but this function will also work fine if it is not.
**
** Parameter zFilename points to a nul-terminated string containing the
** name of the database file on disk to load from or save to. If parameter
** isSave is non-zero, then the contents of the file zFilename are 
** overwritten with the contents of the database opened by pInMemory. If
** parameter isSave is zero, then the contents of the database opened by
** pInMemory are replaced by data loaded from the file zFilename.
**
** If the operation is successful, SQLITE_OK is returned. Otherwise, if
** an error occurs, an SQLite error code is returned.
*/
int loadOrSaveDb(sqlite3 *pInMemory, const char *zFilename, int isSave){
  int rc;                   /* Function return code */
  sqlite3 *pFile;           /* Database connection opened on zFilename */
  sqlite3_backup *pBackup;  /* Backup object used to copy data */
  sqlite3 *pTo;             /* Database to copy to (pFile or pInMemory) */
  sqlite3 *pFrom;           /* Database to copy from (pFile or pInMemory) */

  /* Open the database file identified by zFilename. Exit early if this fails
  ** for any reason. */
  rc = sqlite3_open(zFilename, &pFile);
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){

    /* If this is a 'load' operation (isSave==0), then data is copied
    ** from the database file just opened to database pInMemory. 
    ** Otherwise, if this is a 'save' operation (isSave==1), then data
    ** is copied from pInMemory to pFile.  Set the variables pFrom and
    ** pTo accordingly. */
    pFrom = (isSave ? pInMemory : pFile);
    pTo   = (isSave ? pFile     : pInMemory);

    /* Set up the backup procedure to copy from the "main" database of 
    ** connection pFile to the main database of connection pInMemory.
    ** If something goes wrong, pBackup will be set to NULL and an error
    ** code and  message left in connection pTo.
    **
    ** If the backup object is successfully created, call backup_step()
    ** to copy data from pFile to pInMemory. Then call backup_finish()
    ** to release resources associated with the pBackup object.  If an
    ** error occurred, then  an error code and message will be left in
    ** connection pTo. If no error occurred, then the error code belonging
    ** to pTo is set to SQLITE_OK.
    */
    pBackup = sqlite3_backup_init(pTo, "main", pFrom, "main");
    if( pBackup ){
      (void)sqlite3_backup_step(pBackup, -1);
      (void)sqlite3_backup_finish(pBackup);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_errcode(pTo);
  }

  /* Close the database connection opened on database file zFilename
  ** and return the result of this function. */
  (void)sqlite3_close(pFile);
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting nugget of information, but doesn't address the original question at all. The OP has already exported their database, it's opening it back up that's the problem.  They have a buffer in memory, not in a file, they want to open directly.  The backup API let's you copy to a database (so they could use a blank memory database as the destination), but *the source must be an open database too*. It's a catch 22: to get access to an open database with all their data, they must already have solved their problem!