# Sqlite open in-memory database or file database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I would like to know how the data being read when open a sqlite database file using sqlite3_open function from the sqlite API. I have been thinking the following:

1. the sqlite3_open function read the data every time directly from the database file.
2. the sqlite3_open function copy the file base database to the memory if the system money is enough, lock the database file until updating and closing the database connection. If user select some data from a table, then those data should be from the memory, not from the database file
3. If sqlite_open function open a in-memory database using ":memory:", attach a file base database. this whole database will be a memory base database during program run time?

I saw a discussion on the official sqlite Forum 
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=InMemoryDatabase

and http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Memory-Resident-Database-td42098.html

Do I have to copy my database to memory like following to get the in-memory database for my c++ application?

```
proc loadDB {dbhandle filename} {

if {$filename != ""} {
    #attach persistent DB to target DB
    $dbhandle eval "ATTACH DATABASE '$filename' AS loadfrom"
    #copy each table to the target DB
    foreach {tablename} [$dbhandle eval "SELECT name FROM loadfrom.sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"] {
        $dbhandle eval "CREATE TABLE '$tablename' AS SELECT * FROM loadfrom.'$tablename'"
    }
    #create indizes in loaded table
    foreach {sql_exp} [$dbhandle eval "SELECT sql FROM loadfrom.sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index'"] {
        $dbhandle eval $sql_exp
    }
    #detach the source DB
    $dbhandle eval {DETACH loadfrom}
}
}
```

I like to run a few instances of my application at the same time, if they all share the same database files, it is not safe. Each instance should has their own copy of database in memory at run time

Comment: Ideally you should open the SQLite DB and leave it open for the duration of your app.  The SQLite code maintains a cache of DB pages read from the file, so not every access results in a disk access.  If you keep opening and closing the DB file you have a lot of wasted disk activity.

Comment: The code i posted is from some where else, I may need to rewrite it in c++, my application and sqlite API is written in C++/C

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441450/is-it-possible-to-back-a-readonly-sqlite-database-with-a-memory-buffer-or-pe-re

Comment: can anyone describe how does the cache of DB pages work in sqlite?